# Notation for all permutations of a set

Tags: notation

Suppose I have a finite set $X$. Is there a standard notation to denote the set of all possible permutations of the elements of $X$?

P.S. something like the power set notation for all subsets.

Comment: See if this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Definition_and_first_properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The group of the permutations of $X$ (even if $X$ is infinite) is denoted by : $S(X)$, $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$, or $\mathfrak{S}(X)$.

If $X$ is finite with $n$ elements, it is denoted by $S_n$ or $\mathfrak S_n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Goes $\mathrm{Aut}$ has some meaning?

Comment: @user3761729 the notation makes sense in the context of category theory. The bijection of a set A to itself are the automorphism of A in the category Set. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_sets

Comment: @user3761729 Aut = automorphism group. Set of bijections of the set, under composition. A permutation can be thought of as a bijection from the set to itself.

Comment: Does this change if $X$ is a multiset?

Comment: Is there an accepted notation for the set of permutation *matrices* for a given value of *n*?

Comment: $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ for the group of permutations of $X$ is also used.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for [the symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Definition_and_first_properties) for which there are several notations, e.g. $\mathfrak{G}_X$ or $\mathcal S_X$.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers above, it [can also be denoted by](https://mathoverflow.net/a/344590/74578)

$$X!$$

This notation has the neat property that

$$|X!| = |X|!$$

Comment: Interesting (+1), but not sure I like this notation --- the dual use of $!$ to denote operations on two different objects seems as likely to invite confusion as clarity.