# Notation for union of all permutations of each element in a power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is related to [Notation for all permutations of a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/888211/505227).

I am looking for notation for a set comprising the union of all possible permutations of each element of a power set.

For example, if $A = \{a,b,c\}$, then $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$.

But I am looking for:

$\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{b,a\}\{a,c\},\{c,a\},\{b,c\},\{c,b\},\{a,b,c\},\{a,c,b\},\{b,a,c\},\{b,c,a\},\{c,a,b\},\{c,b,a\}\}$

Comment: The order of the elements in a set is irrelevant $\{a,b\}=\{b,a\}$ so your second set has many duplicates. And duplicates don’t matter either. Both sets are the same.

Comment: Now... if you were to instead talk about the elements in the set you are describing as sequences instead of sets... so $\{\emptyset,a,b,c,ab,ac,ba,bc,ca,cb,abc,acb,\dots\}$ you might be able to get away with something like $\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^\infty A\frac{[n]}{~}$ where here we use the notation that $Y\frac{X}{~}$ is the set of injective functions from $X$ to $Y$ and the notation that $[n]$ is the prototypical $n$-element set (*be that $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ or $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$, it doesn't matter which for our purposes*).

Answer (score 1):

For your example:
{empty set} $\cup$ { {a} : a in A } $\cup$
{ (a,b) : a,b in A, a $\neq$ b) } $\cup$
{ (a,b,c) : a,b,c in A, a $\neq$ b, b $\neq$ c, c $\neq$ a }.

Ordered pairs and ordered triplets are needed because,
for example, {a,b} = {b,a} while (a,b) $\neq$ (b,a).