# Syntax to represent a permutation?

Tags: notation

If I have a set Zn = { 0, 1, …, n-1 }, and I want to indicate that P is a permutation of Zn, is there any mathematical shorthand/symbol that I can use to express this relationship?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notation for all permutations of a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888211/notation-for-all-permutations-of-a-set) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group

$S_X$ denotes the set of permutations on $X$ so you can use
$$P\in S_{Z_n}.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes! Thank you 