# Notation for all permutations of a set as a set of sequences

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, notation

I have a set $S$ of size $n=|S|$. I want the set of all $n!$ permutations of all $n$ elements of $S$, where **permutations are represented as sequences**, and not as bijections.

I have already seen [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888211/notation-for-all-permutations-of-a-set/888212#888212), but it is not what I want. I don't want the permutation group or the symmetric group, I simply want the set of sequences.

For instance, $S=\{1,2,3\}$, and I want to obtain $\{(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)\}$.

Is there a notation to do that, and if not, is there a formula to obtain what I want?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A "formula" to obtain what? If you mean the *number* of those permutation then it is easy to calculate, but if you mean the *list* of them, a formula is not what you are looking for. Formulas usually output values, not lists.

Comment: Not the number (I know it is $n!$), but the set of all permutations as I said. I assume that there should be some sort of formula, because a naive solution could be to do the set of all possible sequences of size $n$ using elements of $S$ (that is, $S^n$) and then remove all sequences with repetitions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you, but I'm not really looking for an algorithm. I'm looking for a conventional notation (for instance $\mathit{Permutations}(S)$) if there exists one, or a formula otherwise.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi no formula could outbut the list you want

Comment: So, this is just a language/notation question? If so, who is your audience, or what is the context in which you need to describe this list? Please answer by editing the question body, not in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, but I thought that by writing "Notation" in the title, by adding the "notation" tag, and by saying "Is there a notation to do that" in the question body it would be clear enough...

Comment: $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$ elements which consists of the $n!$ permutations of those $n$ elements.  You can choose to *interpret* the elements of $S_n$ however you like... as bijections, as sequences, as candy canes... however you like.  We in mathematics *freely switch* between interpretations, just like how we might think of "the number $1$" as the natural number $1$, the integer number $1$, the rational number $1$, and so on... depending on the context we are in... all versions of which having some sense of being "the number 1"

Comment: While to some people there may be a technical difference between the function $f~:~\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3\}$ where $n\mapsto n$ and the sequence $(1,2,3)$... in effect there is not enough of a difference to care about there being a difference between these objects... and in actuality, rigorously since the way sequences are *defined* in the first place, there is not even a rigorous distinction between these objects... they happen to be identical.

Comment: So... even though you say in your post "*I don't want the permutation group or the symmetric group*" the real answer is that you *do* want those and you just did not realize it, having thought that there was some esoteric distinction when there was none.